# How to add API KEY in HTTP Header for URL authentication token in android studio volley?

Tags: android, android-studio, http-headers, android-volley

I have looked into so many sample and codes but still i am getting the response Auth Failed in volley JsonArrayRequest. Can anyone tell what wrong am i doing here.

Below is my code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(act);
    if (isOnline()) {
        pDialog.show();
        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("JSONArray Response", response.toString());

                        try {
                            listener.onResponse(response);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("JSONArray VolleyError", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    listener.onError(timeout, timeoutTitle);
                Toast.makeText(act,
                        "Bad Network, Try again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    listener.onError(poorNetwork, poorNetworkTitle);
                Toast.makeText(act,
                        "Bad Network, Try again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    listener.onError(authorizationFailed, authorizationFailedTitle);
                Toast.makeText(act,
                        "Auth failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    listener.onError(serverNotResponding, serverNotRespondingTitle);
               /* Toast.makeText(act,
                        "Server Not Responding",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    listener.onError(networkErrorMessage, networkErrorTitle);
                Toast.makeText(act,
                        "Network Error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    listener.onError(parseError, parseErrorTitle);
                Toast.makeText(act,
                        "try again"+error.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }

        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //add params <key,value>
                params,put("api_key", "TOKEN");
                params.put("username", "vicky");
                params.put("password", "test123");
                return params;
            }

        }
                ;queue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

i am stuck this for one day.

Comment: Post your log and check you given right api in headers

Comment: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for Url. onErrorResponse: JSONArray VolleyError

Comment: You may given invalid **api_key** kindly check and Its **forbidden error** further google it. Use POSTMAN to validate API call (i.e server request and response). Its plugin in Chrome. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add to the Header, please use `getHeaders()` instead of `getParams()`.